# Hide dynamically created button on static page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have created button on run time using `stringbuilder`

This button will appear on UI & I am also downloading the same page on which button is displayed but I want to hide this button on downloaded page.
How can i hide this button. As download page is using this user control. 
I tried using javascript but it could not access the button's id.

Comment: please show some code and/or markup. it is impossible to solve your problem otherwise

Comment: when creating the button add a display attribute with value false.